# UnboundLocalError : local variable 'toto' referenced before assignment

Tags: django

I got an error with Django and I didn't find a solution :

> UnboundLocalError at /Identity/recherche local variable 'toto'
>   referenced before assignment

This is the part of my script :

```
def Consultation(request) :

    identity = Identity.objects.all().order_by("-id")[:10] #Les 10 dernières fiches créées
    identity_France = Identity.objects.filter(country='64').order_by("-id")[:10] #Les 10 dernières fiches où la personne habite en France

    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query :
        toto = Identity.objects.filter(lastname__icontains=query)        

    context = {
        "identity" : identity,
        "identity_France" : identity_France,
        "query" : query,
        "toto" : toto,
        }

    return render(request, 'resume.html', context)
```

Thank you so much :)

Comment: [Toto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTQbiNvZqaY0)?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Good joke ;) In France, toto is the common variable name :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message says, toto is not defined.

```
query = request.GET.get('q')
if query :
    toto = Identity.objects.filter(lastname__icontains=query)        
else :
    toto = []
```

Or perhaps slightly more pythonic

```
try:
   query = request.GET['q']
   toto = Identity.objects.filter(lastname__icontains=query)        
except KeyError:
   toto = []
   query = None
```

Comment: glad to have helped

Comment: As a beginner, some things are just logic, but it's the first time I'm making that, so it's a pleasure to be helped by people ;)